I do not understand error message 'Binding cannot be changed after is has been used.'
I have 2 textboxes that I need to find in a WPF grid. I've found both of them.  I then bind the the textboxes to properties in a class that uses INotifyPropertyChanged.  The first textbox binds correctly.  The second does not.   I tried creating a new second text box and binding it to the original 2nd textbox property.  I now receive error 'Binding cannot be changed after it has been used'.  I tried clearing the binding using 'BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(textBox02)' but still get the error.  I deleted the 2nd textbox and created another.  It ran once without the error and then the error reappeared.
How to add IValueConverter to an existing Binding
has the same problem.  I tried creating a new binding but get the same error on 2nd run.
I'm very new to WFP. I don't know if the error is telling me that I need to use a new binding, bind to a different property, or replace the textbox.  I've tried all three and still have the problem.  Code for the various areas are below.
Thanks in advance,
Rod McKay
Create the textboxes:
                chartTraderCustomTextBlockArray[1] = new TextBlock()
                {
                    FontFamily = ChartControl.Properties.LabelFont.Family,
                    FontSize = 13,
                    Foreground = ChartControl.Properties.ChartText,
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                    Margin = new Thickness(5, 20, 5, 5),
                    Name = "txtBlock01",
                    Text = string.Format("{0} ", indicatorRiskValue)
                };

                chartTraderCustomTextBoxArray[0] = new TextBox()
                {
                    FontFamily = ChartControl.Properties.LabelFont.Family,
                    FontSize = 13,
                    Foreground = ChartControl.Properties.ChartText,
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                    Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5),
                    Name = "textBox02",
                    Text = string.Format("{0} ", shareQuantity),
                    Height = 20,
                    Width = 240
                };


I used the following code to find the text boxes:
chartWindow = System.Windows.Window.GetWindow(e.Parent) as NinjaTrader.Gui.Chart.Chart;
chartTraderGrid = (chartWindow.FindFirst("ChartWindowChartTraderControl") as ChartTrader).Content as Grid;
textBox00 = chartTraderGrid.FindFirst("TextBox00") as System.Windows.Controls.TextBox;
textBox02 = chartTraderGrid.FindFirst("TextBox02") as System.Windows.Controls.TextBox;

The boxes are found correctly.  I next bind the textboxes to properties in a class that uses INotifyPropertyChanged
Binding binding = new Binding("Quantity");
binding.Source = noOfShares;
textBox00.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding)
Binding binding2 = new Binding("Risk");
binding.Source = noOfShares;
textBox02.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding2);


This is the binding source:
public class NumberOfShares : ObservableObject
{
    private string _risk;
    private string _quantity;
    // Declare the event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public NumberOfShares()
    {
    }
    public string Risk
    {
        get { return _risk; }
        set
        {
            _risk = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Quantity
    {
        get { return _quantity; }
        set
        {
            _quantity = value;
               // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    // The calling member's name will be used as the parameter.
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string quantity = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(quantity));
    }
}

public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyname = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }

}



And where is the code that modifies the existing binding? It looks like you didn't post the complete relevant code. When you want to modify a Binding object you must clone it (or simply create a new instance) and reassign it. Changing an existing Binding is not allowed because it gets sealed as soon it is set to a target property. The idea is that you can use a single Binding instance to establish multiple bindings.

For each usage, the Binding creates an immutable BindingExpression instance, which is the actual underlying binding object that manages a connection between two objects. If you were allowed to modify a used Binding then the framework would have to modify all associated BindingExpressions too. This would lead to potentially unwanted side effects. Because this modification would change ALL bindings and not only the binding of a particular target element that you meant to change. Performance probably was also be on the author's mind. Why this is we can only guess.

Technically more relevant is the fact that BindingExpression is immutable and that the associations are not tracked (a Binding does not remember and does not observe all its created BindingExpressions).

Maybe instead of changing the Binding you should change the source property's value. That's much simpler and more efficient than changing/replacing the Binding.

I think you just have a random typing error.
Correct would be:
Binding binding = new Binding("Quantity");
binding.Source = noOfShares;
textBox00.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding)
Binding binding2 = new Binding("Risk");
// binding.Source = noOfShares; Invalid line
binding2.Source = noOfShares; // Correct variant
textBox02.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding2);

In order to avoid this kind or error, use initializers:
Binding binding = new Binding("Quantity")
{
    Source = noOfShares
};
textBox00.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding)

Binding binding2 = new Binding("Risk")
{
    Source = noOfShares
};
textBox02.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding2);


BionicCode.  Thanks for the explanation.  I've searched everywhere I could think of and your answer finally explains the Binding process to the point that I understand.      EldHasp A Little emabarassed here.  I kept searching for a logic error and it was a TYPO.  Thanks

Great eyes... ;)
